# I can`t go out with while

Tags: python-3.x

```
corect_options = ["KAMIEŃ","PAPIER","NOŻYCE"]

def checking(choice_user,player):
    global corect_options
    user_choice = False
    while user_choice == False:

        choice_user = input("%s wpisz wybór: " % player).upper()

        if choice_user == "KAMIEN":
            choice_user = "KAMIEŃ"
        elif choice_user == "NOZYCE":
            choice_user = "NOŻYCE"
        #print(choice_user)
        if choice_user in corect_options:
            user_choice == True

print("Witaj w grze papier, kamień i nożyce")

player_1 = input("Wpisz nazwę gracza nr 1: ").upper()
player_2 = input("Wpisz nazwę gracza nr 2: ").upper()
lifes = int(input("Wybierzcie liczbę punktów do jakiej będziecie grać: "))
points_1 = 0
points_2 = 0

while points_1 < lifes and points_2 < lifes:
     
    choice_user1 = "something"
    checking(choice_user1, player_1)
```

> Problem with while
> I can`t go out with while loop. What can I correct? This examply value of choice_user1 is necessary?

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: 2 points. Looks like `corect_options` is empty or does not contain required/expected values. 2-nd point, please don't name variables in similar ways `choice_user` and `user_choice`. It makes hard to read your code :)

Comment: It looks like the contents of lifes is an int while the contents of points_1 and points+2 are strings, so they will never compare.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.